# Filter includes false is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am searching an array within my object to return an object with only the matched values in my categories array using filter & includes. For some reason whenever I try to run my function keep getting

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null

or

> TypeError: false is not a function

if I use the find function within my filter.

What am I doing wrong?

```
[{
    "entryTitle": "What Is Sports Medicine Acupuncture?",
    "date": "September 30 2015",
    "categories": ["Knee Pain"],
    "type": false
}, {
    "entryTitle": "Providing Quality Care During The COVID-19 Pandemic",
    "date": "March 23 2020",
    "categories": null,
    "type": false
}, {
    "entryTitle": "Correcting Severe Antalgic Posture & Gait",
    "date": "May 09 2020",
    "categories": ["Back Pain"],
    "type": true
}, {
    "entryTitle": "The Successful Treatment Of Sciatica And Low Back Pain With Sports Medicine Acupuncture®",
    "date": "July 24 2020",
    "categories": ["Back Pain"],
    "type": true
}, {
    "entryTitle": "Treating A Quad Strain For A Super Heavyweight Powerlifter Before The KERN US Open Powerlifting Meet",
    "date": "June 28 2018",
    "categories": ["Knee Pain"],
    "type": true
}, {
    "entryTitle": "Treating A High Hamstring Strain Before A Powerlifting Competition Using Sports Medicine Acupuncture®",
    "date": "June 05 2020",
    "categories": ["Back Pain"],
    "type": true
}, {
    "entryTitle": "Free Acupuncture Treatments For Veterans Through The Veterans Choice Program",
    "date": "June 08 2017",
    "categories": ["Back Pain", "Disc Herniation", "Shoulder Pain"],
    "type": true
}, {
    "entryTitle": "The Treatment Of Whiplash Related Injuries With Acupuncture",
    "date": "March 04 2016",
    "categories": ["Disc Herniation"],
    "type": false
}]
```

My function

```js
const [selected, setSelected] = useState("all")
const [posts, setPosts] = useState(postData)

const filterPosts = value => {
  let posts = postData
  if (value !== "all") {
    posts = postData.filter(post => post.categories.includes(value))
    //posts = postData.filter(post => post.categories.find(post.categories === value))

  }
  setSelected(value)
  setPosts(posts)
}
```

Expected results

```
{
    "entryTitle": "What Is Sports Medicine Acupuncture?",
    "date": "September 30 2015",
    "categories": ["Knee Pain"],
    "type": false
},
 {
    "entryTitle": "Treating A Quad Strain For A Super Heavyweight Powerlifter Before The KERN US Open Powerlifting Meet",
    "date": "June 28 2018",
    "categories": ["Knee Pain"],
    "type": true
},
```

Comment: You will get this error in case of `"categories": null`. So you'd need to ensure that your `categories` is not `null` / `undefined` first, before trying to call `.includes(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This entry

```
{
    "entryTitle": "Providing Quality Care During The COVID-19 Pandemic",
    "date": "March 23 2020",
    "categories": null,
    "type": false
}
```

has `categories` set to null. You can't do includes on it.

Fix it using optional chaining, or check the existence before:

`post.categories?.includes(value)`

or

`post.categories && post.categories.includes(value)`

Answer (score 2):

In `postData` some of  `post.categories` is `null` , so `includes` will not work on this

You need to check for that first and if `categories` available then you can check :

```
postData.filter(post => post.categories ? post.categories.includes("Knee Pain") : false )
```

OR

```
postData.filter(post => post.categories && post.categories.includes("Knee Pain"))
```

---

You can run the below snippet, Nope this will help you :

```js
const data = [{
    "entryTitle": "What Is Sports Medicine Acupuncture?",
    "date": "September 30 2015",
    "categories": ["Knee Pain"],
    "type": false
}, {
    "entryTitle": "Providing Quality Care During The COVID-19 Pandemic",
    "date": "March 23 2020",
    "categories": null,
    "type": false
}, {
    "entryTitle": "Correcting Severe Antalgic Posture & Gait",
    "date": "May 09 2020",
    "categories": ["Back Pain"],
    "type": true
}, {
    "entryTitle": "The Successful Treatment Of Sciatica And Low Back Pain With Sports Medicine Acupuncture®",
    "date": "July 24 2020",
    "categories": ["Back Pain"],
    "type": true
}, {
    "entryTitle": "Treating A Quad Strain For A Super Heavyweight Powerlifter Before The KERN US Open Powerlifting Meet",
    "date": "June 28 2018",
    "categories": ["Knee Pain"],
    "type": true
}, {
    "entryTitle": "Treating A High Hamstring Strain Before A Powerlifting Competition Using Sports Medicine Acupuncture®",
    "date": "June 05 2020",
    "categories": ["Back Pain"],
    "type": true
}, {
    "entryTitle": "Free Acupuncture Treatments For Veterans Through The Veterans Choice Program",
    "date": "June 08 2017",
    "categories": ["Back Pain", "Disc Herniation", "Shoulder Pain"],
    "type": true
}, {
    "entryTitle": "The Treatment Of Whiplash Related Injuries With Acupuncture",
    "date": "March 04 2016",
    "categories": ["Disc Herniation"],
    "type": false
}]

console.log(data.filter(post => post.categories ? post.categories.includes("Knee Pain") : false ))
```

Answer (score 1):

The explanation for `TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null`:  the second entry has `null` `categories`:

```
{
    "entryTitle": "Providing Quality Care During The COVID-19 Pandemic",
    "date": "March 23 2020",
    "categories": null,
    "type": false
}
```

Perhaps you want `post => post.categories!==null ? post.categories.includes(value) : false`

The explanation for `TypeError: false is not a function`: [`a.find` accepts a function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)  `find` will run that function on each entry of `a` and return the first entry which returned `true`.  So you should use `post.categories.find(category => category===value)`.  (What you have doesn't make sense, since an array can't equal the value.)

Answer (score 0):

You could check for `categories` first as follows:

`post.categories && post.categories.includes('Back Pain')`

```js
const postData = [{
    "entryTitle": "What Is Sports Medicine Acupuncture?",
    "date": "September 30 2015",
    "categories": ["Knee Pain"],
    "type": false
}, {
    "entryTitle": "Providing Quality Care During The COVID-19 Pandemic",
    "date": "March 23 2020",
    "categories": null,
    "type": false
}, {
    "entryTitle": "Correcting Severe Antalgic Posture & Gait",
    "date": "May 09 2020",
    "categories": ["Back Pain"],
    "type": true
}, {
    "entryTitle": "The Successful Treatment Of Sciatica And Low Back Pain With Sports Medicine Acupuncture®",
    "date": "July 24 2020",
    "categories": ["Back Pain"],
    "type": true
}, {
    "entryTitle": "Treating A Quad Strain For A Super Heavyweight Powerlifter Before The KERN US Open Powerlifting Meet",
    "date": "June 28 2018",
    "categories": ["Knee Pain"],
    "type": true
}, {
    "entryTitle": "Treating A High Hamstring Strain Before A Powerlifting Competition Using Sports Medicine Acupuncture®",
    "date": "June 05 2020",
    "categories": ["Back Pain"],
    "type": true
}, {
    "entryTitle": "Free Acupuncture Treatments For Veterans Through The Veterans Choice Program",
    "date": "June 08 2017",
    "categories": ["Back Pain", "Disc Herniation", "Shoulder Pain"],
    "type": true
}, {
    "entryTitle": "The Treatment Of Whiplash Related Injuries With Acupuncture",
    "date": "March 04 2016",
    "categories": ["Disc Herniation"],
    "type": false
}];

const filteredResult = postData.filter(post => post.categories && post.categories.includes('Back Pain'));
console.log(filteredResult);
```